# PHP creating array (Code refactoring)

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, associative

Hey below is the code that I am currently working with, it does it's job but I am calling it multiple times from within another loop. Could anyone suggest a cleaner way to rewrite this code?

```
$list = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $number ; $i++) {
          array_push($list, array('text'=>$i, 'value'=>$i));
}
return $list;
```

In general it usually just creates an associative array counting up to the number passed to it.

i.e.

```
array (size=100)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => int 1
      'value' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => int 2
      'value' => int 2
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => int 3
      'value' => int 3
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => int 4
      'value' => int 4
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => int 5
      'value' => int 5
   5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => int 6
    value' => int 6
```

Sorry if this question isn't very relevant on this site, I'm trying to teach myself better coding practices and I can't think of where else to ask this question.

For some reason the phrase array mapping comes to mind when rewriting the function but I am struggling to find any examples.

Comment: Can you show the other loop?

Comment: Hi. think about, probably you don't need to create arrays right away in an other loop. probably store number(from what you create array) into another array just for indexing purpose. so you'll have array of MAX indexes. So you will be able to create your simple array after and use it at the place you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's better in any way, but it sounds like this is what you were getting at:

```
$list = array_map(function($a) { 
    return array('text' => $a, 'value' => $a); 
}, range(1, $number));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$list = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $number ; $i++) {
          $list[] = array('text'=>$i, 'value'=>$i);
}
return $list;
```

It'll stop the `array_push` function call on each iteration.